# How to reset background color of ::selection

Tags: css, semantic-ui

```
/* Site */
::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: @highlightBackground;
  color: @highlightColor;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: @highlightBackground;
  color: @highlightColor;
}
::selection {
  background-color: @highlightBackground;
  color: @highlightColor;
}
```

I am using semantic-ui as css framework, and I have been overriding its values today. I came across with selection option, which is overridden by default, and I would like to set it as computer default. As some of you know, you can change selection color in macbooks, so I would like my users to use computer's default selection color.

So, what should I do? I tried inherit and transparent but they don't work.

Comment: Have you tried `initial` or `unset`? Browser support may vary, but those keywords should do it.

Comment: @cyonder You should find default color and replace it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It does not work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol They don't work.

Comment: @alirezasafian there is no default color. Default color is whatever user set in his/her computer. So, it depends on computer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is to use the system color `highlight` for the background and `highlighttext` for the foreground.

Colors like `inherit` won't work, because `inherit` means "use the same color as the parent element". That's not what we want!

The first example sets the selection colors to yellow on brown, to emulate the framework theme. Just to make sure changing those colors works at all.

```css
/* colours from theme */
::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}
::selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a div in which you can make a selection</div>
```

Then we'll add the colors `highlight` and `highlighttext` to the end of the css (emulating our custom stylesheet) to show that the selection color is back to the default.

```css
/* colours from theme */
::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}
::selection {
  background-color: brown; color: yellow;
}


/* overriding colors */
::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: highlight; color: highlighttext;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: highlight; color: highlighttext;
}
::selection {
  background-color: highlight; color: highlighttext;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a div in which you can make a selection</div>
```

Disclaimer: these system colors are officially deprecated; there is no proper replacement yet though. Also, in Chrome it seems to reset the colors to slightly different ones than they have in the absence of any styles; I seem to have to do some more research.

Comment: Not working in Chrome 61, I get a lighter blue than selecting other text on the page using the default theme.

Comment: @Goombert That's right; that's what I meant with my remark "in Chrome it seems to reset the colors to slightly different ones than they have in the absence of any styles".

Comment: I've submitted a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=757028

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors
highlightText & highlight colors are deprecated =(

Comment: @MarkosyanArtur That's right; that's what I meant with my remark "Disclaimer: these system colors are officially deprecated".